# Compare Two Strings with Greater than or Lower than Android Studio

Tags: java, string, android-studio

i want to compare Two Strings

X = Users Input

Y = System Input

if X is Greater than Y

than show greater than

if X is lower than Y

than show Lower than
Here is my code but it is not working

```
    if (X.compareTo(Y)>-1)  
    {
       Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "Greater Than", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
   else {
      Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "Lower Than", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
```

Comment: Define “not working”.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your `> -1` is a clever way of testing for "is equal to or greater than". I suggest avoiding such clever code. Writing **stupid-simple code** ([KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)) makes reading and, more to the point here, *debugging* much easier.

The `compareTo` method of [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface returns exactly zero if equal. If not equal, the method returns some number greater than zero, or some number less than zero.

To quote the Javadoc:

> Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

So change your test to check every single possibility to see how the `String#compareTo` implementation’s behavior does not match your expectations. Make four checks, for equals zero, greater than zero, less than zero, and a fall-through to catch if you ever mistype the first three.

By the way, variable names should start with a lowercase letter, per Java naming conventions. So `x`, not `X`.

```
int comparison = x.compareTo( y ) ;
if ( comparison == 0 )  {
    …
} else if ( comparison > 0 )  {
    …
} else if ( comparison < 0 )  {
    …
} else { 
    … Oops, the “if” tests must be flawed. We should never reach this point. 
}
```